# How copy files and skip the loader for building sass in esbuild?

Tags: esbuild

I'm working on a esbuild file for a project. Got it almost ready but 3 problems:

1. How skip loader for the sassPlugin, because I'll want to use the copyFiles function and not let the loader create files
2. Errors in the sass are not refrenced to te source file but to the bundle file
3. Copyfiles gives an error "Could not resolve `src/images`"

this is my setup for now:

````
/**
* Requirements
*/
const esbuild = require('esbuild');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

/**
* Plugins
*/
const chokidar = require('chokidar');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync');
const { sassPlugin } = require('esbuild-sass-plugin');
const { copy } = require('esbuild-plugin-copy');

/**
* Variables
*/
const url = 'http://localhost/domain.com/public/';
const dist = 'public/resources/dist/';
const srcJs = 'src/js/bundle.js';
const srcScss = 'src/scss/bundle.scss';
const srcImages = 'src/images/';
const isProduction = process.argv.includes('--production');

/**
* Create JavaScript build
*/
async function buildJS() {
   const jsConfig = {
       entryPoints: [srcJs],
       bundle: true,
       minify: isProduction,
       sourcemap: !isProduction,
       platform: 'browser',
       outdir: dist + '/js/',
   };

   await esbuild.build(jsConfig).catch((error) => {
       console.log(error);
   });
}

/**
* Create Sass build
*/
async function buildSass() {
   const sassConfig = {
       entryPoints: [srcScss],
       bundle: true,
       outfile: dist + '/css/bundle.css',
       minify: isProduction,
       sourcemap: !isProduction,
       plugins: [sassPlugin({})],
   };

   await esbuild.build(sassConfig).catch((error) => {
       console.log(error);
   });
}

async function copyImages() {
   const copyConfig = {
       entryPoints: [srcImages],
       outdir: dist + '/images/',
       plugins: [
           copy({
               assets: [{ from: './src/images', to: './public/dist/images' }],
           }),
       ],
   };

   await esbuild.build(copyConfig).catch((error) => {
       console.log(error);
   });
}

/**
* Development build with watch mode and BrowserSync
*/
async function serve() {
   // Build all files
   buildAll();

   // Create BrowserSync server
   const server = browserSync.create();

   server.init({
       proxy: url,
   });

   // Watch JavaScript files
   const jsWatcher = chokidar.watch('./src/js/**/*.js', {
       awaitWriteFinish: true,
       ignoreInitial: true,
   });

   jsWatcher.on('change', (path) => {
       console.log(`JavaScript file ${path} changed. Building...`);
       buildJS().then(() => {
           server.reload();
       });
   });

   jsWatcher.on('error', (error) => {
       console.error('JavaScript watch build failed:', error);
   });

   // Watch Image files
   const imageWatcher = chokidar.watch('./src/images/**/*', {
       awaitWriteFinish: true,
       ignoreInitial: true,
   });

   imageWatcher.on('change', (path) => {
       console.log(`Image file ${path} changed. Building...`);
       buildSass().then(() => {
           server.reload('*.css');
       });
   });

   imageWatcher.on('error', (error) => {
       console.error('Image watch build failed:', error);
   });

   // Watch Sass files
   const sassWatcher = chokidar.watch('./src/scss/**/*.scss', {
       awaitWriteFinish: true,
       ignoreInitial: true,
   });

   sassWatcher.on('change', (path) => {
       console.log(`Sass file ${path} changed. Building...`);
       buildSass().then(() => {
           copyImages().then(() => {
               server.reload('*.css');
           });
       });
   });

   sassWatcher.on('error', (error) => {
       console.error('Sass watch build failed:', error);
   });
}

/**
* Production build
*/
async function buildAll() {
   await Promise.all([copyImages(), buildSass(), buildJS()]);
}

/**
* Call correct function on init
*/
if (!isProduction) {
   serve();
} else {
   buildAll();
}```
````